# How to activate a filter by default on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

[image: Context]

Here is a visual of my report in Power BI.

I have a gauge and two filters. 
I would like to activate by default the OPEX filter when I arrive on the report. 
So I have played with the element filter and checked only OPEX but when I do this the CAPEX filter disappears.

My goal is to highlight the OPEX filter at the opening of the report but let the possibility to desactivate it and activate the CAPEX filter for example (or desactivate the two filters).

Do you know how I can achieve that ? 
Thank you by advance.

Comment: What kind of filter (visual) ar you using? When I use the default filter and set it to horizontal, the behaviour is exactly like you wanted.

Comment: I'm using the ChicletSlicer but you're right I haven't seen that, thanks a lot TJ !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways I know how to accomplish your requirement of of highlighting the OPEX filter at the opening of the report: If you are showing your report using Power Bi Desktop, I recommend you use [Bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks).

To do this, make sure the Bookmarks feature is on (it was a preview feature prior to the March 2018 of Power Bi desktop).  Then go to your report and slice the data using the OPEX button.  Then create a new bookmark and name it "OPEX".  Once you do this, you can link to this book mark from the top page or index of your presentation.

Second way of saving this report state if it is published to Report Server or Service is to use [URL filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters).   Browse to the report with your browser, select the slicer or apply the filter and the URL will change.  Then copy the resulting URL and link to it in your report presentation index or top page.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't the last update of Power Bi Desktop but that seems very interesting ! I didn't know about the URL filtering, I think that's the perfect solution in my case, thank you Taterhead !